# PHP bug or what am I wrong?

Tags: php

```
function dec2sat( $decimal )
{
    return $decimal * (10**8);
}

echo dec2sat(0.06999206); // result: 6999206 (float type)

var_dump(dec2sat(0.06999206) >= 6999206); // result: FALSE
```

Could everyone please explain to me why `var_dump(dec2sat(0.06999206) >= 6999206);` return FALSE?

Tested: PHP 7.2.12, PHP 7.1.22, PHP 5.6.38

Comment: be sure is not a rounding problem  try compare  dec2sat( 0.06999205) or dec2sat( 0.06999207)

Comment: or try: `echo number_format(dec2sat(0.06999206),15);`.

Comment: @scaisEdge, not rounding problem, `echo dec2sat(0.06999206); // result: 6999206 (float type)`. Most of the results are correct, I do not understand why the number 0.06999206 results in wrong

Comment: @duyvu1311 No, it's definitely a rounding issue.  `var_dump((int)dec2sat(0.06999206));`

Comment: @PatrickQ, No, Do not cast to int, leave it float type, if you cast to int, the result is: 6999205, not 6999206

Comment: @duyvu1311 Exactly.  That's the point I was making.  That's the cause of the issue.  You're comparing a fixed int to a float that does _not_ have the same value.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to compare float against integer. In that case PHP needs to explicitly convert float to integer. When you run code below:

```
var_dump((int)dec2sat(0.06999206)); // 6999205
```

you will get number 6999205 which is obviously less then 6999206.

Same thing is when you try to compare string vs integer. This will output true:

```
var_dump('string' == 0); // true
```

This is way you need always to compare type and value, to avoid this kind of behavior. Code below will output true, it is not some beautiful solution but it works. Try with other cases as well.

```
var_dump(round(dec2sat(0.06999206), 0) >= 6999206); // true
```

> WHY THIS HAPPENS:

Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format, which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when several operations are compounded.

Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like 7.9999999999999991118....

In our case when you strip all hidden digits behind decimal dot you will get next results:

```
var_dump(number_format(dec2sat(0.06999206), 30, '.', '')); // 6999205.999999999068677425384521484375
var_dump(number_format(dec2sat(0.06999206), 9, '.', '')); // 6999205.999999999
var_dump(number_format(dec2sat(0.06999206), 8, '.', '')); // 6999206.00000000
```

> CONCLUSION:

Never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp functions are available.

Either convert your returned value to integer or round it up to 8 decimal places.

Comment: How about this code snippet? `$a = 6999206;
    var_dump(dec2sat(0.06999206) >= (float)$a);` It still returns false

Comment: Give me few minutes to figure out some solution

Comment: REMEMBER: Most of the results are correct, I do not understand why the number 0.06999206 results in wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
function dec2sat($decimal)
{
    return $decimal * (10 ** 8) . '';
}
```

Comment: Yes, but why? Could you please explain why?

Comment: I suggest you to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - Try to bring some context to your answer and directions for the asker.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I want to say is: Thank you very much for spending your time to find out the solutions for my question. The main goal for my question is not to find out the solution, I need to know the reason which causes above unexpected result because it helps me avoid repeating later.
After taking a look at the answer of Aleksandar Rakić, I did some search about float type in PHP and now, I think I have found the reason cause `var_dump(dec2sat(0.06999206) >= 6999206);` return `FALSE`. You can read here: [Warning: Floating point precision](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

I think the number `0.06999206` is not really `0.06999206`, it may be `0.069992059999...` when storing internally and the function `dec2sat(0.06999206)` results in `6999205.999...` This is why the solution of Aleksandar Rakić return expected result.

Here is the edited `dec2sat()`

```
function dec2sat( $decimal )
{
     return intval(round( $decimal * (10**8) )); // $decimal always has decimal value <= 8 digits
}
```

The main goal of the function `dec2sat()` is to convert `floating point number` to `int` to avoid processing `floating point number` directly in my app.